# Should I use Oort or write my own forwarding using CometD, when nodes don't need to know about each other?

Tags: load-balancing, cometd

My app will work as follows:

I'll have a bunch of replica servers and a load balancer. The data updates will be managed outside CometD. EDIT: I still intend to notify each CometD server of those updates, if necessary, so they can respond back to clients.

The clients are only subscribing to those updates (i.e. read only), so the CometD server nodes don't need to know anything about each other's behavior.

Am I right in thinking I could have server side "client" instances on the load balancer, per client connection, where each instance listens on the same channel as its respective client and forwards any messages back to it? If so, are there any disadvantages to this approach, instead of using Oort?

Reading the docs about Oort, it seems that the nodes "know" about each other, which I don't need. Would it be better then for me to avoid using Oort altogether, in my case? My concern would be that if I ended up adding many many nodes, the fact that they communicate to "each other" could mean unnecessary processing?

Answer (score 0):

The description of the issue specifies that the data updates are managed outside CometD, but it does not detail how the CometD servers are notified of these data updates.

The two common solutions are A) to notify each CometD server or B) to use Oort.

In solution A) you have an event that triggers a data update, and some external application performs the data update on, say, a database. At this point the external application must notify the CometD servers that there was a data update. If the external application runs on a JVM, it can use the CometD Java client to send a message to each CometD server, notifying them of the data update; in turn, the CometD servers will notify the remote clients.

In solution B) the external application must notify just one CometD server that there was a data update; the Oort cluster will do the rest, broadcasting that message across the cluster, and then to remote clients.

Solution A) does not require the Oort cluster, but requires the external application to know exactly all nodes, and send a message to each node.

Solution B) uses Oort, so the external application needs only to know one Oort node.

Oort requires a bit of additional processing because the nodes are interconnected, but depending on the case this processing may be negligible, or the complications of notifying each CometD server "manually" (as in solution A) may be greater than running Oort.

I don't understand exactly what you mean by having "server side client instances on the load balancer". Typically load balancers don't run a JVM so it is not possible to run CometD clients on them, so this sentence does not sound right.

Besides the [CometD documentation](http://docs.cometd.org/3/reference/), you can also look at [these slides](http://www.slideshare.net/SimoneBordet/cloud-messagging-cometd).

Comment: Thanks for your help!!! From what you're saying in your last paragraph (listening as a beginner in clustering and load balancing) a typical load balancer would handle forwarding all the CometD messages for me, if I opted for approach A)? So it's even simpler than I described. Am I right? Would this work ok for any of the transport types in CometD?

Comment: The load balancer should only stick the same client to the same server, and then it's mostly out of the picture.
A remote client1 will connect and be directed by the load balancer to node1, remote client2 will connect and be directed to node2, etc.
When node1 is notified of the data update, it will notify the remote clients connected to it. Sure the messages from node1 to its remote client pass through the load balancer, but it's nothing more than what a basic load balancer does, there is no additional logic to be put into the load balancer apart sticking the same client to the same server.

Comment: Oh that's sweet - makes things simple. Will this work ok for both websockets and http transport types in CometD, without any issues?

Comment: Whether it works with WebSocket depends on the load balancer, HTTP is not a problem. You have to stick on the client address not HTTP headers, of course. [HAProxy](http://haproxy.org) can do it, for example.

Comment: Wonderful. Oort has "all-to-all" topology, yes? Would you consider adding an option for "ring" topology so it scales to 100s of nodes? This is the only thing holding me back from using Oort right now since each new node demands a little more processing on the master node. Am I missing the mark? I feel if Oort had a "ring" or "each-to-n" single loop (i.e. scalable) topology option I'd use it for all data updates across the cluster. You're by far the best qualified to add in this option but I'd be happy to contribute in source with your advice if you're too busy to add it in yourself.

Comment: CometD is designed for large scalability: with Jetty and a commodity server 200,000 remote connections are not a problem. If the connections become 200,499 because you have 500 nodes, it's not a big difference from 200,000, so we never went to more complicated topologies.  I can be convinced otherwise with more details, so feel free to join the [CometD mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cometd-users) to propose your ideas, or discuss what is holding you back.

Comment: I wasn't thinking about the connection number but the message passing. Does passing a potentially high traffic of messages from one master node to 499 nodes not take any more noticeable processing than, say 1-to-1 or 1-to-2 per node? That is the scalability that's holding me back from using Oort. I require a master node to handle all data write operations for validation. Then transaction info will be passed to replica nodes to update their data & to respond to CometD clients. For this I think a "ring"/"each-to-n" single loop topology would be perfect, but I might be missing something.

Comment: For CometD sending  a message to 500 clients is a no-brainer. I cannot tell whether a ring approach would be better without writing a benchmark for your specific case. What message rate are we talking here ? And besides, what you are doing looks pretty much like what [OortObject](http://docs.cometd.org/3/reference/#_java_oort_objects) provides. Are you aware of OortObject ?

Comment: No I'm learning :) Reading about OortObject I can't seem to fit it in. I'll have a db on a master node. "Write" operations from all clients are directed to the master node for validation, db is updated, then transaction info sent to replica nodes to update their dbs & respond to listener clients. All "read" operations are load balanced across all nodes including master. I need the master node to remain as responsive as possible to clients when attempting to write, no matter how many nodes are added. What message rate? Let's suppose 2 million publishing a 500 byte transaction per second.

Comment: You have 2M transactions/s on a single db server ? That's about

Comment: You have 2M transactions/s on a single db server ? That's about 500 ns per transaction, and 8 GiB/s of traffic to that server, it's pretty extreme. What database and network are you using ?
Back to CometD, you can use an OortService for the writes, and update an OortObject on the master node to update the replica nodes. See [CometD Support](http://docs.cometd.org/3/reference/#_support) if you're interested in taking this further: we can discuss it in more details and explain how we can help you out.

Comment: No I'm building for that capacity :) I'll probably use either Prevayler or Blazegraph for my db. I am a pre start up with no budget except my own savings. Instinctively the current "to all" messaging of Oort doesn't seem suitable for what I'm making because the fact that processing on the master node increases with node number, no matter how little, always raises a "what if" concern which simply doesn't exist with "ring" or "each-to-n" single loop messaging topology. So for now I'll either build my own messaging system that does this, or contribute the option to CometD if it's as easy?

Comment: It is easy to contribute to CometD, see [here](http://docs.cometd.org/3/reference/#_contribute). I'd love to discuss this in more details in the CometD mailing list. However, I would make it work with CometD first, because you can get something working very quickly, and then worry about scalability: you can always add the ring solution (or build your own messaging) later. Building your own messaging will be a huge effort just to get the infrastructure going (instead of spending time on code that does business). You may want to concentrate on features first, rather than infrastructure.